# Как подтвердить получение данных на COM-порту

Tags: c#, com-порт

Пришлось работать с COM-портом. Однако устойчивой работы добиться не удалось.
Недавно узнал, что каждое событие поучения данных из COM-порта,

```
    private void _port_DataReceived(object sender, 
         SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
       ......
    }
```

нуждается в подтверждении того, что данные приняты и обработаны. 
Вопрос:Как это сделать в C#?

Comment: немножко не понятно,вы хотите кому подтвердить прохождение данных, отсылающему или уведомить получающий узел что данные которые он получил, обработаны?

Comment: Надо уведомить порт, что данные, находящиеся в его буфере прочитаны и очистить сам буфер.

Answer (score 0):

С проблемой разобрался.
После каждой операции чтения-записи в COM порт необходимо принудительно очищать его буферы с помощью команд
          p.DiscardOutBuffer();
          p.DiscardInBuffer();

Comment: Странные Вы вещи говорите. Чтение очищает буфер в достаточной степени, а эти топорные методы зачем? Может, Вы как-то неправильно с портом обращаетесь? ()

Comment: Топорные методы, или нет, но они помогли...